# .Net EF core DbContext.Save() during multiple Async functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-core

I am being puzzled with how dbcontext.SaveChanges(). Based on documentation SaveChanges() should save all the changes made to the Database.

Consider the case in which I have multiple Async functions from which all of them target different tables. If all of them try to create new entries but some take longer than others (due to computation processing etc) will the First function to reach dbcontext.SaveChanges() save all changes made by other Async functions regardless if those functions have reached the SaveChanges part?

So my concern is that during multiple Async functions data will be saved prior to the BusinessFlow just because another function said SaveChanges().

Is this the case or do they create some internal transaction scope for each async?

Startup.cs can be found here https://github.com/drakoumel/DatacircleAPI/blob/master/Startup.cs

Comment: If you mean you are using the same dbContext instance from multiple threads, and even doing multiple SaveChanges in parallel - don't do that. Never use the same context from multiple threads - just create separate one for each parallel operation.

Comment: I have a web API, that creates a dbcontext during startup, i dont know if it is the same connection every time an controller action is being called

Comment: Show us your code, please. Especially how you are injecting/using DbContext. I agreed with @Evk. You should have no problem if are injecting DBConext in a proper way. The transaction will be created automatically for you in each instance of DbContext, so it's important to create a new instance for each thread - in fact, it will be done for you if you will inject DBContext in each thread.

Comment: That's what I'm saying - don't do that, don't create it at startup. Create new context instance whenever you need, perform operations you need, call SaveChanges if necessary.

Comment: Sorry for this I forgot to add the link to the repo. You can take a look at the Startup.cs and then at Database/ApplicationDbContext.cs the init for the EF models etc and at any Repository you can see I inject the DbContext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to understand how all that will behave, you need to know how and with which lifetimes your context and repositories are registered in DI container.

Context is registered like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));
```

If you will look at arguments of AddDbContext method, you will see that it has contextLifetime argument, with default value of ServiceLifetime.Scoped. So context is registered with Scoped lifetime.

Repositories are registered as

```
services.AddScoped<IDatasourceRepository, DatasourceRepository>();
```

So, also with Scoped lifetime.
What scoped lifetime means? It just means new object is created *per request* when resolving at DI container. So now you know that you have single instance of your repositories and your context **per request**, and as such, different calls to your controller actions use different instances of context, so their SaveChanges cannot interfere with each other.

Comment: Ahh I didnt know that AddDbContext defaults to Scoped. Thanks a million man!